# Unity Animation doesn't play, error instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
public class BasicMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animation anim;

    public float jumpPower = 15f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool canJump;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.Play("Run");
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // FIX LATER for collider, not position
        if (rb.position.y <= -2.95) // this is line 23
        {
            canJump = true;
        }

        if (canJump)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {

                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
                canJump = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Object reference not set to instance of object: 23

For some reason, if I take `anim.Play("Run");` out, then there is no error at all.

Also, I made the `RUN` and `JUMP` animations to the gameObject this script is assigned to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use  `anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();` instead of Animation, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The GameObject which has this script doesn't have the `Animation` component added to it, giving you `null` when you're trying to fetch it with `anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();`

Make sure your Animation component is added to the GameObject and then try again!

Comment: Now i get another error: The animation state Run could not be played because it couldn't be found!
Please attach an animation clip with the name 'Run' or call this function only for existing animations.

I added the Animation component to it, and also the Run animation to it.